# Remove the edit button in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with a couple of cells witch can be edited. I want to remove the edit button in the toolbar if there are no cells in the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `rightBarButtonItem'` to nil:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

When you want to show the edit button again, set it to `self.editButtonItem`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Answer (score -2):

You should implement this method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in tableview delegate. There you can return appropriate editing style for your cells: UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete for deletable cells, UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone for others

so if u don't have any row, put you table view style UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone

Comment: The question is "How to remove edit button" (which is most likely on the nav bar)